# Need to increase the length of Y axis in a horizontal bar chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I want to fix the space between two bars in canvas as a certain number in horizontal charts.

**What I am expecting is as shown below:**

[image: This is what I am expecting]

**What I am getting:**

[image: This is what I am getting]

As the number of rows increasing the gap between the ticks is reducing, how to fix to certain number?

I had tried this afterfit to change the scale height , but it didn't work:

```js
var labels = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= 500; i++) {
    labels.push('Category ' + i);
}

var data1 = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= 500; i++) {
  data1.push(i * 10);
}

var data2 = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= 500; i++) {
  data2.push(i * 3);
}

const data = {
        'labels': labels,
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Bar 1',
            data: data1,
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(100, 149, 237, 0.25)',
            barPercentage: 1, // Adjust the bar width for Bar 1
            categoryPercentage: 1 // Adjust the spacing between categories
        }, {
            label: 'Bar 2',
            data: data2,
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(100, 149, 237,0.8)',
            barPercentage: 0.8, // Adjust the bar width for Bar 2
            categoryPercentage: -1 // Adjust the spacing between categories
        }]
    };
    
const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');

const config = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: data,
  options: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        indexAxis: 'y', // Set the chart to display horizontal bars
        scales: {
          x: {
                beginAtZero: true,
                position: 'top' 
            },
            y: {
              beginAtZero: true,
              afterFit:function(scale){
                debugger;
              }
            }
        },
        plugins: {
            legend: {
                display: true
            },
            layout: {
            padding: {
                left: 20,
                right: 20
            }
        }
        }
    }
};

new Chart(ctx, config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could dynamically define the height of the `canvas` depending on the number of bars your chart contains.

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('myChart');
const headerHeight = 75;
canvas.height = barCount * 25 + headerHeight;
```

Please take a look at your amended code and see how it works.

```js
const barCount = 500;

var labels = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= barCount; i++) {
  labels.push('Category ' + i);
}

var data1 = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= barCount; i++) {
  data1.push(i * 10);
}

var data2 = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= barCount; i++) {
  data2.push(i * 3);
}

const data = {
  'labels': labels,
  datasets: [{
    label: 'Bar 1',
    data: data1,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(100, 149, 237, 0.25)',
    barPercentage: 0.8
  }, {
    label: 'Bar 2',
    data: data2,
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(100, 149, 237,0.8)',
    barPercentage: 0.6
  }]
};

const canvas = document.getElementById('myChart');
const headerHeight = 75;
canvas.height = barCount * 25 + headerHeight;

const config = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: data,
  options: {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    indexAxis: 'y',
    scales: {
      x: {
        beginAtZero: true,
        position: 'top'
      },
      y: {
        beginAtZero: true,
        stacked: true
      }
    },
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: true
      },
      layout: {
        padding: {
          left: 20,
          right: 20
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

new Chart(canvas, config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```